# From a Hilbert space to another Hilber space, is a norm preserving invertible transformation also unitary?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Given two Hilber spaces -  $H_1, H_2$ and a transformation $T:H_1 \to H_2$ that is norm preserving and invertable, does this imply that $T$ is also unitary transformation, namely that it preserves the inner product? 
[or equivalently: is it true that - 
$a,b, \in H_1 \langle a,b\rangle_{H_1} = \langle T(a),T(b)\rangle_{H_2}$]

Any comments are welcome!

Comment: Can you use polarization identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes** if $T$ is linear, because the norm determines the inner product via the [polarization identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity)
$$
\langle x,y\rangle = \frac14 \sum_{n=0}^3 i^n \|x+i^ny\|^2
$$

**No** if $T$ is allowed to be nonlinear: a counterexample is given by $(r,\theta)\mapsto (r,\theta +\frac12 \sin\theta)$ in polar coordinates in the plane.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response, a small clearification... Don't you have to assume here that - $\|T(A)-T(B)\| = \|A-B\|$? I can't see why this should be true...

Comment: @user90793 I do, which is correct when $T$ is linear. $T(A)-T(B)=T(A-B)$. If you allow $T$ to be nonlinear (which should have been specified in the question), then there are counterexamples, even in two dimensions: $(r,\theta)\mapsto (r,\theta+\frac12\sin\theta)$   in polar coordinates.

Comment: Thats it, thanks!